# symfony2 given Forbidden when application moved to server

Tags: php, linux, symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.1

I've tried to move symfony2 web application to my web server but application return me always "Forbidden" error.

```
    You don't have permission to access /app-name/ on this server.
```

Also, i've tried to create new empty application by command line using composer but error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a plain permission error in your filesystem/serve.

Does your www user have permission to access the /app-name/ on your server?

Comment: Sure. It's not permission problem but maybe php version it's lower than framework request.